# Break when hotkey is pressed

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, breakpoints

I'm doing a lot of GUI and graphics stuff and sometimes it would be convenient to break the running program when I press a hotkey.

Example: I want to analyze behaviour that depends on the current mouse position. I would like to place an inactive breakpoint, move the mouse to the interesting spot, press some hotkey, and voilà: The breakpoint is now active and a moment later (e.g. next repaint) the program breaks.

Is there some hidden Visual Studio 2008 feature that can do that?

Comment: Sounds to me you just need a 2nd monitor.  Consider setting a condition on the breakpoint.

Comment: How exactly would a second monitor help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Ctrl + Break?

**Edit**
Or, for only when conditions are met, you could use `Debug.Assert(condition)` to specify a condition. I believe it asks you if you want to edit/continue/close the program when the condition is false.

Comment: Ctrl + Break doesn't work (assuming you mean "Break all", which, for some reason is Ctrl + Alt + Break on my system). It needs the focus on the visual studio window and breaks exactly where the program currently is, not at the point where I want it to be.

Comment: If VS has no hidden feature to explicitly break on hotkey, then, yes, using conditional breakpoints is probably the best solution.

Comment: @Sebastian N. - Ctrl+Break works for me to go to the currently executing line, but yes, I don't think there's any way to turn on and off line breaks via a hot key.